# Putting javascript inside html label tags

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript and currently have a task to make a multi choice question with shuffling answer options (using radio object to select an answer and a shuffling array). I have successfully made a shuffling array using the code below.

```
<script>
var array = ['Coding','programming','debugging','maintenance'];
var i = array.length, j, temp;

while (--i > 0) {


j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
temp = array[j];
array[j] = array[i];
array[i] = temp;
}


document.write(array);
</script>
```

However, I cannot figure out how to take the output of the array and put it inside the html code recommended to me, in order to make the radio buttons for selection.

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a"/>
<label for="q1b">'array 1 option would go here'</label>
```

I could very well be on the entirely wrong track, but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the label and set its content like

```js
var array = ['Coding', 'programming', 'debugging', 'maintenance'];

var cp = array.slice(0),
  i = 0,
  j;
while (i++ < array.length) {
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * cp.length);
  document.querySelector('label[for="q' + (i) + 'b"]').innerHTML = cp[j];
  cp.splice(j, 1);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a" />
<label for="q1b">'array 1 option would go here'</label>
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q2a" />
<label for="q2b">'array 1 option would go here'</label>
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q3a" />
<label for="q3b">'array 1 option would go here'</label>
<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q4a" />
<label for="q4b">'array 1 option would go here'</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common and simple way to get around this is to assign the item you want to place text in an `id`, for example `#label_q1b`. Then change it's `.innerText`:

```
<label id="label_q1b" for="q1b"></label>
```

Then in your last line other than `document.write` do:

```
document.getElementById("label_q1b").innerText = array;
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbyqab9y/)

Answer (score 0):

You can run your JavaScript code in label as shown below.

```
<label>
<script>
document.write("test");
</script>
</label>
```